# Manipulate QML Canvas from C++ in Qt5

Tags: c++, audio, qml, qt5, visualization

In my **Qt5** application I have some *C++* and some *QML* working in harmony (aka sending signals back and forth).

At this point I want to implement a widget that shows a real-time updated visualization of a playing audio stream in forms of the actual waveform showing in my QML. So I wonder which alternatives ways exist to solve this? What is the easiest alternative to code and which alternative has the best performance?

My naive ideas are:

- Create a Canvas in my QML and then draw directly to this canvas from C++
- Send actual samples as a buffer to QML and draw them in canvas from js
- Send actual samples as a buffer to QML and draw them in some other manner
- Write a custom C++ widget and somehow display that in QML

PS: I already have access to the actual samples to generate the visualization from, however if you have a clever solution to this as well then I would be overjoyed!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subclass [QQuickItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html). Also, there is a subclass, [QQuickPaintedItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html) that allows you to draw with a QPainter.

Here you have an [example of QQuickPaintedItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html) usage